# Dynamically alloceted array, double free or corruption

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I understand that this error came from double deleting the allocated memory and in theory I know what should be done. But it seems to doesn't work the way it should. Or I do sth wrong. Please help.
Here's code of my class:

```
typedef int SIZE_TYPE;

template<typename T>
class CArrays{
private:
    SIZE_TYPE size;
    T * tab;
public:
        // methods...
    };


template<typename T>
CArrays<T>::CArrays(T value, SIZE_TYPE argsize){

    size = argsize;
    tab = new T[size];
    for(SIZE_TYPE i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(tab+i) = value;
    }

template<typename T>
CArrays<T>::~CArrays(){

    delete [] tab;

}

template<typename T> template<typename J>
CArrays<T> & CArrays<T>::operator=(const CArrays<J> &rhs){
    if(&rhs != this){
        this->size = rhs.size;
        delete [] this->tab;
        this->tab = new T[this->size];
        memcpy(this->tab, rhs.tab, sizeof(J) * rhs.size);

    }
    return *this;
}
```

And when i do in my main.cpp sth like that:

```
CArrays<int> a(3, 10), b(0, 10);
b = a;

*** glibc detected *** ./out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000087b010 ***
```

Comment: You're missing the copy constructor.

Comment: Condensing something to a MCVE does not mean arbitrarily removing things. The important things, like ctors, dtors, op= and whatever else might be relevant should be kept.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Likely, though we cannot say. He blacked out too much.

Comment: Probably the simplest solution is to use `std::vector`. Then all your allocation problems just go away. Just from the code you've down your `operator=` will break when `T` or `J` are non-POD or if they have different sizes.

Comment: Also, if the template type is non-POD, you can't use `memcpy` to copy over the data.  But that assignment operator looks very unorthodoxed.  What is the purpose of using `template <typename J>` here?

Comment: Ok thank you all. it was a matter of this "extra" template<typename J>. I don't really know why i put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

**Usage of `memcpy` to copy data.**

If the template type `T` is a non-POD type, you cannot use `memcpy` to copy over the data.  You have to copy the items one-by-one, or use `std::copy`

**If you haven't coded one, you are missing the copy constructor.**

Here is what it should look like:

```
template<typename T> 
CArrays<T>::CArrays<T>(const CArrays<T> &rhs)
{
    tab = new T[rhs.size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rhs.size(); ++i )
         tab[i] = rhs[i];
    size = rhs.size;
}
```

**The assignment operator is peculiar.**

Maybe not wrong, but strange.  An assignment operator would/should look like this (given that the copy constructor and destructor are working correctly):

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T> 
CArrays<T>& CArrays<T>::operator=(const CArrays<T> &rhs)
{
    CArrays<T> temp(rhs);
    std::swap(temp.size, size);
    std::swap(temp.tab, tab);
    return *this;
}
```

The above works, due to copying and swapping out the internals of a temporary object with the existing objects, and letting the temporary die off.

In the last two items, I'm assuming that the only members are `tab` and `size`.  If there are other members, please copy them also (and swap them out) in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Especially for usage of memcpy. Now everything works fine.